# How do I define "class attributes" in emberjs?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Say I'm sub-classing ("extending") Ember.View to create My.Widget. I'd like each My.Widget sub-class to have a 'class attribute' called 'XMLTag' that can be used for de-serializing from an XML document.

```
My.Widget = Ember.View.extend( { /*...*/ });
My.MySubWidget = My.Widget.extend( { /*...*/ });
My.MySubWidget.XMLTag = 'MySubWidget';
```

Is this the right way to go about this? Or is there some sort of trick I can use in "extend()" to specify that its a class attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to extend class level variables or methods is reopenClass(), e.g.:

```
My.SubWidget.reopenClass({
  xmlTag: 'mysubwidget'
});
```

Simply adding the property to My.SubWidget will *not* be retained if you further extend the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can add classes via the `classNames` property on an `Ember.View`: This property is an array of strings which are added to the `class` attribute of a concrete view. Since it is a so called *concatenated property*, sub-classes do not overwrite the `classNames` of the superclass, but extend it - so the superclass class names are not overwritten.

I created an example, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/xMBQ4/:

```js
My.Widget = Ember.View.extend({
    classNames: 'my-widget'.w(),
    didInsertElement: function(){
        var classes = this.$().attr('class');
        console.log(classes);
    }
});
My.MySubWidget = My.Widget.extend({
    classNames: 'my-sub-widget XMLTag'.w()
});

My.MySubWidget.create({
    classNames: 'class1 class2'.w(),
    templateName: 'mySubWidget'
}).append();​
```

This prints the following when the `My.MySubWidget` view is added: `ember-view my-widget my-sub-widget XMLTag class1 class2`.

Comment: When defining `classNames`, you don't need to add `.w()` to the end. It accepts a space-separated string as well.

Comment: But if you do a `console.log(this.get('classNames'))` you'll see that the `classNames` are not split so the output is `["ember-view", "my-widget", "my-sub-widget XMLTag", "class1 class2"]`. It doesn't matter because in the end the `class` attribute of the DOM representation is just a string. But omitting the `w()` - or not defining it as array - on `classNameBindings` will not work, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/mGFUh/.

Comment: I think the OP means "class" as in class versus instance, i.e., he wants a class variable.

Comment: @ChristopherSwasey you're probably right. I've read the question too quickly.